# How to use Clang with MonoDevelop on OS X?

Tags: macos, monodevelop, clang

I want to use Clang++ instead of gcc when working with MonoDevelop on OS X Lion, but MonoDevelop options only show gcc and g++. How do I use Clang++ with MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement an extension. You could do this in an addin, or do it in the main C/C++ addin itself (the gcc compiler support is implemented as an extension in the C/C++ addin).

Here  are some links that may help:

- [Creating a simple addin](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Creating_a_Simple_Add-in).
- [The source of the gcc compiler extension](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/CBinding/Compiler/GccCompiler.cs).
- [Where the gcc compiler extension is registered as a serializable class](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/CBinding/CBinding.addin.xml#L225).
- [How to build MonoDevelop from source of MacOS X](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X).